# How can I query ancestral relationships in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm reading the documentation for tree structures here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

The hierarchy is:

Books -> Programming -> [Languages, Databases -> [Postgres, MongoDB]]

In the documentation it says:

The query to retrieve the parent of a node is fast and straightforward:

```
db.categories.findOne( { _id: "MongoDB" } ).parent
```

That makes sense. However, how can I run a query based on attributes of the ancestor? For example, instead of just retrieving the parent, suppose I wish to find all documents where the grandfather has an _id of "Books" how would I do that? The answer should be "Languages" and "Databases".

Comment: You might be able to check the ancestors by looking for a match at a particular index. (Honestly, graph databases aren't MongoDB's sweet spot).

Answer (score 0):

If your tree structure is fixed. You can query by following way, before that, just change your MongoDB structure by following URL,

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-nested-sets/

to get all ancestor of Databases,

```
var databaseCategory = db.categories.findOne( { _id: "Databases" } );
db.categories.find( { left: { $lt: databaseCategory.left }, right: { $gt: databaseCategory.right } } );
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : "Books", "parent" : 0, "left" : 1, "right" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "Programming", "parent" : "Books", "left" : 2, "right" : 11 }
```

to get all descendant of Databases,

```
var databaseCategory = db.categories.findOne( { _id: "Databases" } );
db.categories.find( { left: { $gt: databaseCategory.left }, right: { $lt: databaseCategory.right } } );
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : "MongoDB", "parent" : "Databases", "left" : 6, "right" : 7 }
{ "_id" : "dbm", "parent" : "Databases", "left" : 8, "right" : 9 }
```